# Need timer countdown resetting to 60 when ends with Observables or in any way in Angular2

Tags: rxjs, angular2-observables

I am developing bidding website in Angular2. I need a timer for every product, which starts at 60 seconds and when it gets to 0 it resets again to 60.

```js
countDown;
counter = 60;

constructor() {
        this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
            .take(this.counter)
            .map(() => --this.counter);
}
```

The counter starts with 60 seconds and ends up with 0. But I can't implement reset part which  reassigns 60 again to counter when its value gets to 0.

I know little about Obervables in RxJs. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

We can use some math to achieve this. **Please read bonus part to see an alternative**

```js
this.countDown = Observable
  .timer(0, 1000) // emits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8...
  .map(tick => 60 - (tick % 60)); // emits 60, 59, 58... 0, 60, 59...
```

We're taking the rest of division by 60 - `tick % 60`

```
1 % 60 = 1
2 % 60 = 2
...
60 % 60 = 0
61 % 60 = 1
...
```

If we want to count down from 60 then we need to subtract the rest of division from 60.

**Bonus (answer to the question in the comment)**

If you want to start with a random number, you have to keep some kind of state in the observable. [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) operator serves this purpose. In this scenario, using [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) operator is an overkill and we can use [`interval`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) instead.

```js
function getRandomNumber() { // returns a random integer from 1 to 60
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
}

Observable
      .interval(1000) // emits every second
      // `scan` works like `reduce` method of the array
      // it keeps its own internal state in `acc`
      // `acc` initial value is random and when it reaches 1, it has a new random integer assigned to it again
      .scan(acc => acc === 1 ? getRandomNumber() : acc - 1, getRandomNumber());
      // emits e.g. 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6...
```

Technically you can solve original problem by replacing `getRandomNumber` with a desired number.

Comment: if I want to start countDowns randomly numbers what should I do? For example: 1. Product -> 25 sec -> 60sec->60sec ; 2.Product -> 14 sec -> 60sec->60sec and etc